# MySql MBRCONTAINS not accurate

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 3 column. city_id, city_name and city_geo. city_geo type is geometry. and i have a another table that has a vehiclelog. I want to query if the latitude and longitude from vehiclelog table is inside the city_geo. I can get the result but not so accurate it's also get the Point that **near** in city_geo. this is my query

```
        SELECT  v.`City`,v.`Time`,c.`city_name`,v.`Latitude`,v.`Longitude`
        FROM `city` c, `vehiclelog` v
        WHERE c.`city_name`='$c' AND v.`plate`='$p' AND v.`Date` = '$d'
        AND  MBRCONTAINS(c.`city_geo`, POINT(v.`Latitude`, v.`Longitude`))
```

I plot it on google map to verify the result and i get

[image]

as you can see there are markers outside the polygon that are not suppose to include in result I want only the markers inside the polygon or city_geo. Im using MySql v5.0 I also try MBRCONTAINS, MBRCrosses, Contains and Crosses all same result.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL's result seems correct... `MBRCONTAINS()` tests whether the Minimum Bounding Rectangle of one object contains the other object.

Does the smallest possible rectangle you can draw around the polygon... contain those points?  Visually, it certainly appears that it does.

To test whether the polygon, itself (not the MBR) contains the point, the function you want is `ST_Contains()`, which was introduced in MySQL 5.6.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html

Comment: Ya `ST_Contains` can solve my problem but the problem is my webhost godaddy the latest version of there mysql is only v5.5. So i dont have a choose i just make a php file that check if the the lat long is outside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

This function will work similarly to `ST_Contains` in older versions (like 5.1)!

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE FUNCTION GISWithin(pt POINT, mp MULTIPOLYGON) RETURNS INT(1) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 

DECLARE str, xy TEXT; 
DECLARE x, y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, m, xinters DECIMAL(16, 13) DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE p, pb, pe INT DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT MBRWithin(pt, mp) INTO p; 
IF p != 1 OR ISNULL(p) THEN 
RETURN p; 
END IF; 

SELECT X(pt), Y(pt), ASTEXT(mp) INTO x, y, str; 
SET str = REPLACE(str, 'POLYGON((',''); 
SET str = REPLACE(str, '))', ''); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, ','); 

SET pb = 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str); 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p1x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p1y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, xy, ','); 

WHILE pe > 0 DO 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p2x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p2y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
IF p1y < p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y > m THEN 
IF p1y > p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y <= m THEN 
IF p1x > p2x THEN SET m = p1x; ELSE SET m = p2x; END IF; 
IF x <= m THEN 
IF p1y != p2y THEN 
SET xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x; 
END IF; 
IF p1x = p2x OR x <= xinters THEN 
SET counter = counter + 1; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
SET p1x = p2x; 
SET p1y = p2y; 
SET pb = pe + 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str, pb); 
END WHILE; 

RETURN counter % 2; 

END; 
//
DELIMITER ; 

-- usage example: 


SET @x = -79.12345678901234; 
SET @y = 43.12345678901234; 
SET @point = CONCAT('POINT(',@x,' ',@y,')'); 
SELECT id FROM polygons WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), polygon_data);
```